# How do I copy an Xbox 360 game to the HDD?

Tags: xbox-360

How do I copy Xbox 360 games to the HDD?

I would like my games to load faster with little to no lag.

Answer (score 27):

1. Insert the game disc into the disc drive.
2. From the "Xbox Dashboard", go to "My Xbox".
3. Select the game you want to install.
4. Press **Y** on your controller.
5. Select "Install to Hard Drive".

**Notes:**

- Installing an Xbox 360 game might take several minutes.
- Multidisc game? Install each disc to your hard drive.
- Installing an Xbox 360 game on a hard drive requires between 4 and 8 gigabytes (GB) of free disc space.

[image]

Comment: Also be aware that some games suffer when installed, e.g. Halo 3 (because it caches data from DVD to HD, and so (when installed) ends up caching stuff from HD to itself).

Comment: Rawling is correct, but in general, most new games are going to be faster and have better performance when installed. Halo 3 came out  before the NXE (new dashboard) was released with the ability to install games, so it wasn't optimized for that type of performance.

Comment: One small addition: Running the game still requires the Disc in the drive, and Multi Disc games still require disc swapping. This is for copy protection purposes.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. Maybe someone can update it.

Answer (score 3):

Select a game and press Y button, there will be an option to install it to a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was like this:

With the DVD inside, go to Games -> My Games. Select Game Details with your <kbd>X</kbd> button and choose Install.

Comment: For me it was my games then x button for details then install